# Facebook Login error in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to implement Facebook Login in Android. Facebook login button appears well. When I click it, it popups modal like page that has an exit button on its left upper corner. 
When I click an exit button, the program dies with the below log.

```
05-02 18:57:50.914 2247-2291/com.hahaha E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
05-02 18:57:50.922 2247-2291/com.hahaha
 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
05-02 18:57:50.922 2247-2291/com.hahaha
 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
05-02 18:57:50.924 2247-2291/com.hahaha
 E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
05-02 18:57:51.197 2247-2247/com.hahaha
 W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

I tried to put error log when I got into "cancel" mode. However it seems it doesn't put log in that case. I really want to know why suddenly the app drops ( I think it doesn't die because otherwise I should see the popup error message.)

My code looks like below.

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"로긴 성공",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                info.setText(
                        "User ID: "
                                + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                                + "\n" +
                                "Auth Token: "
                                + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                );info.setText(
                        "User ID: "
                                + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                                + "\n" +
                                "Auth Token: "
                                + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                );

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
                Log.i("what","canceled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"로긴 실패",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // App code
            }
        });



@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sungpah, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

..
```

I'm looking forward to seeing any opinions!

Best

Comment: try this ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android  check your facebook sdk.